# Save FabricJS canvas as JPG/PNG upon link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using FiberJS to create a template and I used the following way to trigger save popup upon a link click. But it does not save anything or does not return any data when canvas.toDataURL() is called.

```
<a id="canvasdownload" download="canvas-image.png" href="">Download</a>

$('a#canvasdownload').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', canvas.toDataURL());
    alert(canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

But this saves a blank image with an error. With native canvas behavior this saved properly but not after using FabricJS. How can I fix this?

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n5brg7dv/).

Comment: can you provide fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: It will save black image because your href will be "" when you will click on it ; you are changing it after on its click till then download would have already started.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n5brg7dv/

Comment: try $('a#canvasdownload').click(function(){
        var iframe = $("<iframe/>").attr({
                        id: 'dummyiFrame',
                        src: canvas.toDataURL(),
                        style: "visibility:hidden;display:none"
                    })
        $('#dummyiFrame').remove();
    });

Comment: @Jugnu nope. it didnt work in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n5brg7dv/3/

Comment: it is because of cors issue but if you will load image from you local files then it should work otherwise images from other domain can't be saved using toDataURL()

Comment: @Jugnu but when I used the native HTML5 canvas methods with external images it saved upon the click. That is why I am confused here.

Comment: @techytee For very valid security reasons, in both FabricJS & native canvas `.toDataURL` will be disabled if an image from a different domain than the webpage itself is drawn on the canvas. **The fix:** Serve the image on the same domain as the webpage. Alternatively, you can configure the image server to deliver that image with special headers that won't cause the canvas to disable `.toDataURL`. Here's a 'how to` link: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: @markE thank you (y)

Comment: After setting the correct cors header in the server,rember to set bg.crossOrigin = 'anonymous' on your bg object. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/n5brg7dv/4/